# composer update error on fresh installation of laravel 5

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

After i get fresh installation of laravel 5 via composer create-project laravel/laravel i tried to update composer.json file via composer update but alway get this error. Someone knows why?

```
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Applicat
ion::getCachedCompilePath() in /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vendor/laravel/framework/sr
c/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ClearCompiledCommand.php on line 28
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/ar
tisan:36
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vend
or/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:94
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/ve
ndor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/Code/zadar
plus/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
PHP   6. Illuminate\Console\Command->run() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vendor/symfony/
console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:101
PHP   8. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vendor/symf
ony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
PHP   9. Illuminate\Container\Container->call() /home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vendor/lar
avel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:115
PHP  10. call_user_func_array:{/home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vendor/compiled.php:925}()
/home/vagrant/Code/zadarplus/vendor/compiled.php:925
PHP  11. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClearCompiledCommand->fire() /home/vagrant/Code/
zadarplus/vendor/compiled.php:925
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems something went wrong during the "compilation".

Delete `vendor/compiled.php` and run composer update again.

If that didn't work out, delete `storage/framework/compiled.php`, too.